# SCONS build failed ( I am using RT Thread)

Tags: multithreading, scons

Failling to build SCONC while using RT Thread library:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build
CC build/applications/lcd_init.o
In file included from /home/blue/rt-thread/include/rtthread.h:24:0,
                 from applications/lcd_init.c:1:
/home/blue/rt-thread/include/rtdef.h:87:9: error: unknown type name 'rt_uint32_t'
 typedef rt_uint32_t                     rt_time_t;      /**< Type for time stamp 
scons: *** [build/applications/lcd_init.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Please tell us what you are trying to compile.  If it's a package you downloaded from some where please include a link to that repo/download location.  If it's your own code, please share your SConstruct.

Comment: I am new to this I tried some packages using scons --menuconfig and then pkgs --update to get the package then I used scons. The error was too big so was't able to post here

Comment: You failed to provide any of the information I asked for above. Please do so I can help you.

Comment: I am not compiling anything.   https://github.com/RT-Thread/rt-thread

Comment: You are compiling something. That's what SCons does. It compiles code.  Please provide the command line which provided the above output. Also more info. Did you clone the rt-thread repo and just type scons ? how did you get the above?  Most likely you should file a bug against the rt-thread repo.

Comment: Are you using rt-thread's env tool?

Comment: Yeah I am using Rt-thread Env tool. I just went to scons --menuconfig added some pacakges and then save .config file then j types scons and got the above error.

Comment: You'll likely need someone who's familiar with rt-thread's env tool usage to solve this issue. It's not SCons specific, but rather rt-thread's usage of SCons.

Comment: Okay Thank you I will look over it. Thanks a lot for spending your time to help me out